# Anyone know why my Rails AJAX call isn't working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I hit my submit button on the form, it's triggering a response, but it's not refreshing my page with the new object. Help?

Terminal Response

```
Started GET "/activity/individual?utf8=%E2%9C%93&pub_date=02%2F27%2F2016+-+02%2F29%2F2016&influencer_id=22" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-18 11:55:54 -0700
Processing by ActivityController#individual as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "pub_date"=>"02/27/2016 - 02/29/2016", "influencer_id"=>"22"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "accounts"."slug" FROM "accounts" INNER JOIN "accounts_users" ON "accounts"."id" = "accounts_users"."account_id" WHERE "accounts_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "influencer_feeds"  WHERE "influencer_feeds"."influencer_id" = 22 AND "influencer_feeds"."influencer_id" = 22 AND ("influencer_feeds"."pub_date" BETWEEN '2016-02-27 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-02-29 00:00:00.000000')
  Rendered activity/individual.js.haml (0.1ms)
```

Controller

```
def individual
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Form

```
 = form_tag("/activity/individual", format: 'js', method: "get", remote: "true", multipart: 'true') do
 (parameters)
=submit_tag
```

JS

```
- if params[:mode] == "append"
  $('#activity_feed_container').append('#{j (render "activity/individual", feed: @feed, influencer: @influencer, twitter_account: @twitter_account, type: @type) }')
- if params[:mode] == "new"
  $("#activity_feed").html('#{j (render "activity/individual", feed: @feed, type: @type) }')
  $("#activity_feed_container").data("page", 1)
$(".show_more_div").show()
- if (!@feeds || -1 == @feeds || (@feeds && @feeds.count < Settings.activity_feed.page_size))
  $(".show_more_div").hide()

:plain
  if($('body').hasClass('ie9')){
    IE.resizeCols()
  }
```

Activity/Individual View (activity/_individual.html.haml)

```
.fluid-row
  = render "discovery/prospect_rank", prospect: @influencer_prospect

-if (can? :individual, Activity)
  - if @feed.blank?
    .fluid-row
  .panel
    %p= "No Activity Content for this Influencer"
  - else
.activity-feed-toolbar
  = form_tag("/activity/individual", format: 'js', method: "get", remote: "true", multipart: 'true') do
    .fluid-row
      .small-5.columns
        %h3 Activity Feed
      -if can? :filter_individual, Activity
        .small-7.columns
          .fluid-row
            .small-6.columns
              #date_range.dates
                -# %input.activity_data_range{:type=>"text"}
                %input#pub_date{name: 'pub_date', :type=>"text", :placeholder => " mm/dd/yyyy - mm/dd/yyyy", value: @pub_date}/
                %div.calendar-overlay
            .small-6.columns
              .activity-feed-filter
                -# = select_tag "activity_filter_select", options_for_select({'Last 200 Tweets' => 'last_200', 'Most Recent Relevant' => 'all', 'Relevant Twitter' => 'twitter', 'Relevant RSS' => 'rss'}), class: "filter-select"
                = hidden_field_tag :influencer_id, params[:influencer_id].to_i
            .small-2.columns.secondary-search-filters
              = submit_tag "Apply", {:name => nil, class: 'feed-filter button', id: 'override-default-button-margin-bottom'}

.fluid-row
  .small-12.columns.no-padding.feeds-container#activity_feed_container{:data => {:page => 1}}
    = render partial: 'influencer_feed/feed', locals: {feed: @feed}

.fluid-row
  .small-12.columns.no-padding
    - if @page.to_i <= @total_pages
      .show_more_div.center
        %a.button.radius.center.case-normal.activity_show_more#global_activity_pagination

:javascript
  $(document).off( "mouseup", "body");
  activityFeedSearchOptions()
  DatepickerRange.init()
```

Comment: What do you have in your `activities/individual` view?

Comment: i don't think you need `format: 'js'  and method: "get"`, just `remote: true` would do the trick, and try change `format.js` to `format.js { render layout: false }`

Comment: @lusketeer I made those changes. Still nothing.

Comment: @Uzbekjon Edited - Added the view. I understand it's not standard rails routes :(

Comment: in your js file, try to change all the `render` partial codes to something like this `render partial: "activity/individual", locals: { feed: @feed, type: @type }`

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "*it's not refreshing my page with the new object*"? Also, you don't have `params[:mode]` sent with your form.

Comment: @lusketeer Added that, but no changes :(

Comment: @Uzbekjon I was thinking about that, where do I put params[:mode] in my form? I can't find anything on google on that.

Comment: Just add a hidden field `= hidden_field_tag :mode, 'YOUR-MODE'`.

Comment: shouldn't you use a POST request ?

Comment: I think get because I'm not trying to write data. But I did try post and I don't have the routes for that.

Comment: @GrahamSlick I have a similar page that uses a get and it works, but it's not using remote js.

Comment: @BrianLau where is yr JS located, what file ist ?

Comment: @7urkm3n in activity/individual.js.haml and the view is activity/_individual.html.haml. Notice I don't have a activity/individual.html.haml.

Comment: @BrianLau, do you call somewhere expect in JS that partial `_indvl.html.haml`

Comment: @7urkm3n Are you telling me to change my JS to render partial: activity/_individual.html.haml?

Answer (score 0):

@lusketeer was correct. Adding in the locals helped. But I also needed to change the JS because it wasn't fetching the params[:mode] properly. So I just made it:

```
- if params[:mode] == "new"
  $("#activity_feed").html('#{j (render "activity/individual", locals:     { feed: @feed, type: @type}) }')
  $("#activity_feed_container").data("page", 1)
- else
  $("#activity_feed").html('#{j (render "activity/individual", locals: { feed: @feed, type: @type, pub_date: @pub_date}) }')
```